# Looking for any way to transfer file from PPC to PC

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i looking for any way to transfer file from PPC to PC - and from PC to PPC ,
i dont want to use WebService, and if i use RAPI i need that in the PC will be any program - and i dont want
(i dont want that in the PC will be any of my program)

how i can do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to be more specific -- the way the question is now it's basically impossible to determine what you're after.

Do you need to transfer a file from a Windows Mobile handheld to a Windows PC?  Over what type of connection (are they on the same 802.11 network) ?

You need more details or no one will be able to even attempt to help you.

Comment: OK, i explane. i need to transfer file from PPC to PC through ActiveSync - but in the PC there isnt any PC program .
when i press the button in my C# program in the PPC -> the file will transfer from the PPC to PC to d:\Temp (for example)

Answer (score 0):

So, if what I gather is correct, you want to plug a device with your app on it into a PC and then be able to push files to the PC from the device without having to install anything over on the PC.  Is that correct?  If so, the next question is are you insane?

It's not possible, and for very good reason.  You don't see any potential security problems with being able to just plug a device into a PC and push files up to the PC without the user having to explicitly have installed something to receive that data?  I could write a simple attack app that would fill up the PC's hard drive in about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla version of this is to just use the Active Sync synchronization folders. If you on the device save a file to the device synch folder, then Active Sync will move it over to the PC synch folder automatically.